# Storing custom objects in an NSMutableArray in NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

HI,
How can i store NSMutable array in NSUserDefaults?
regards
shishir

Answer (score 1):

Storing the array is as easy as:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:array forKey:@"array"];
```

but every object in the array must be a property-list object. That is, they must be one of:

- NSArray
- NSDictionary
- NSString
- NSData
- NSDate
- NSNumber

If you want to store instances of other classes in a property list, you must create methods to serialize/deserialize them to and from one of these types. Serializing objects to dictionaries is a common approach.

**EDIT:** Another approach is shown here: [How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: this is not working for me sir,

i m inserting objects into an array,and i want that array should be in NSUserdefault. 

regards
shishir