# can NSUserDefaults carry object of class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, nsuserdefaults

I use NSUserDefaults  as following

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    BOOL downloaded = [prefs boolForKey:@"downloaded"];


    if (! downloaded ) {


        [self MoveAndBuild ];

        [prefs setBool:YES forKey:@"downloaded"];   


        //////////// Write to the file to prevent re import at the next time .





    }
```

my question is can NSUserDefaults carry object of class , I mean I have a class and want to save object of it to be act as default is applicable , 
another question can NSUserDefaults  store nsstring

any suggestion please

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation for NSUserDefaults](http://tinyurl.com/5rgrlbj)? I ask because the third paragraph of the Overview section answers your question and points you to more information.

Comment: the problem was in the encoding part see the answer , don't judge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom class object needs to implement the `NSCoding` protocol.

Check the below SO post.

[How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 2):

We use NSUserDefaults to store objects, and an object can be of any type i:e NSString, NSArray, Class Objects etc.
For Storing you can use:

```
[defaults setObject:anyObject forkey:@"objectKey"];
```

Comment: Developer "and an object can be of any type" part of your answer is incorrect. please edit your answer.

Answer (score 0):

NSUserDefaults can store (and only store) plist-objects. please see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/UserDefaults.html for programming NSUserdefaults.

Comment: Ah I see: the objects a property list can store. Anyway: this answer is wrong. Any NSCoding compliant object can be stored, as [Jhaliya](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340031/nsuserdefaults-question/6340092#6340092) pointed out.

Comment: @vikingosegundo "The NSUserDefaults class only supports the storage of objects that can be serialized to property lists. This limitation would seem to exclude many kinds of objects, such as NSColor and NSFont objects, from the user default system. But if objects conform to the NSCoding protocol they can be archived to NSData objects, which are property list–compatible objects" excerpt from the documentation. There is no direct way to store non plist objects, even though NSCoding complaint. You need to archive it to get NSData, which is a plist compatible object.

Comment: But the OP is about NSUserDefaults. and not plist

Comment: @AMH can you please let me know if I understod your question properly ? finding it difficult to understand @vikingosegundo perspective :)