# How to save conversation history in instance messager?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm constructing an internal instance messager app which is very similar to whatapps. Can someone give me suggestions of how to save the conversation in the local device. Is it ok to archiver the whole UIViewController to save all the messages?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of choice , like you could store in **sqllite**  database , As object using **NSUserDefaults** and as **file** in your application sandbox.

And file could be either `xml` or simple `txt` format.

Updated:

[How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: Thanks can I archive the UIViewController and save it to the NSUserDefaults?

Comment: Thanks Jhaliya I will take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

No you need to save history either into NSUserDefaults or save into Sqlite Database.

Comment: I'm also thinking to save the data into NSUserDefaults (cause my boss doesn't want to use the database approach). Could you please provide more detailed information of how to do so? I'm planning to archive the UIViewController and save to the NSUSerDefaults. I don't know whether it is possible or not. Cause it sounds strange to archive the UIViewController.