# How to count the number of objects save into NSUserDefault?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a question about NSUserDefault. Currently, i wanna write a function which save the favorite school into a list.

I have school name and school Id. So each time I save, school name + school id will be 1 dictionary object.

Then I save into NSUserDefault base on the id as key. I want to know the number of objects I saved into NSUserDefault. Or How can I get all of the objects out of NSUserDEfault since each of my key is different. Please help me out. below is my code:

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


NSMutableDictionary *schools = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[schools setObject:schoolName forKey:kSchoolName];
[schools setObject:schoolID forKey:kSchoolID];

[userDefault setObject:schools forKey:schoolID];
```

Comment: In such cases, I find it easier to store an entire array in NSUserDefauts like "favourite_schools" or something and use it

Comment: Saving an array to `NSUserDefaults` is perfectly explained here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2315972/1141395 . Its much easier and you don't have to save any keys you used for saving. If your objects have also arrays which should be saved remember to add `NSCoding` to the objects inside the array too.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How many objects are you storing? Maybe this isn't the best use for `NSUserDefaults`.

But to directly answer your question:

```
NSUInteger count = 
  [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] count];
```

Comment: Nice answer, didn't know its possible to print all saved items.

Comment: I get a 19-digit number when I try to print using po [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] count]  in the debug screen

Comment: If I create a dictionary from standardUserDefaults with NSDictionary  * defaultDict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]; and view it in variables window it shows 275 key/value pairs including general Mac ones like AppleLocale.

Comment: 19 digit number was an address... casting to NSInteger gave 275

Answer (score -2):

You would want to use a same key to store your schools dictionary.I mean,

```
[userDefault setObject:schools forKey:@"Schools List"];
```

Then to retrieve it

```
    NSDictionary *schools = [userDefault ObjectforKey:@"Schools List"];
   [[schools allkeys]count];
```

That will give you the count.

Comment: The question was, how to get a list of all items inside `NSUserDefaults` and not how to save and load a single object. This is offtopic.