# Persistent Storage to store class objects

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Want to know ways to store **OBJECTS** of a *Class* in some persistent storage. (like PLIST or sqlite). But as far as i know we cannot STORE objects of a class in PLIST.

Comment: read this, I think it will help  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store the objects as persistent object in your application you can use NSKeyedArchiver, There is a very nice blog written by Si Ma: http://keeptheseinmind.blogspot.in/2011/10/nskeyedarchiver-tutorial.html

There is a video as well: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Eb0J3sn4z08

Please mark it as correct answer if helps...;)