# Objective C - Store EAAccessory to NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, external-accessory, eaaccessory

In a project I have to make,
I am working with external accessories, and the framework ExternalAccessory.

(I can connect to **one and only one** accessory).

The connection is easy, sending data is not really difficult.

One thing I would like to do is to store in memory the last connected device, to try to reconnect to it automatically when the application relaunch. (after leaving, so after the first launch.)

So, my problem is that EAAccessory is a custom class object, and could not be stored into NSUserDefaults.

I saw this question to store custom objects :

[How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

So I would create a NSData with it, but did not succeeded, because EAAccessory does not implements the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder methods...

Any idea ? For this way or another way to process ?

Answer (score 0):

You should store logically/in a meaningful way that makes sense all the important and persisten properties of the EAAcessory instance in an NSDictionary and store this dictionary in NSUserDefaults. Then you will have to read back this dictionary and perform the inverse convertion (alloc-initting the EAAccessory instance, setting its properties, etc.)

Comment: Sure, but I think I can make something easier :)

Comment: Not really. That's how this logic works. How do you think various classes' encodeWithCoder: etc. implementation has been coded? ;)

Comment: Yeah, this is why I like these classes or methods that simplify my life :)
I am a developer, so I do not want to code too much... ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement the missing methods into a custom EAAccessory category.
Maybe somthing like this :

```
*** interface
@interface EAAccessory (CodecAdditions)
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder;
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder;
@end

*** implementation 
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeInt:[self name] forKey:@"name"];
    [aCoder encodeInt:[self manufacturer] forKey:@"manufacturer"];
    ...
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self.name = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"name"];
    self.manufacturer = [aDecoder decodeIntForKey:@"manufacturer";
    ...

    return self;
}
```

Comment: Okay, I tried something like this, but in the init function, I would begin with a :
self = [super init]
if (self) {
...
}

And got and error because EAAccessory does not have a parent class.

I'll try it again !

Comment: Hummmm after another try, this solution does not work, because of EAAccessory properties are readonly.

So I cannot make a self.name = ...