# iOS: Storing selected table view rows in userDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

In my app I have a tableview which allows user to enable or disable elements by tapping the rows. Quite simply, I need to store each row's condition in userDefaults - if it's turned on, or not. How would I go about this?

I was thinking I could add a BOOL property to the object each row represents for whether or not its enabled but how would I go about doing remembering the value of the property for each individual object?

Answer (score 0):

You could use some kind of id on each row to be able to identify a particular row. Then you could create an custom object and store it in NSUserDefaults.

[Look at this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a bunch of setting keys:

```
// SET
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"setting1_ON"];
[defaults setBool:NO forKey:@"setting2_ON"];

// GET
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
bool setting1 = [defaults boolForKey:@"setting1_ON"];
bool setting2 = [defaults boolForKey:@"setting2_ON"];
```

Or store one array of all settings (or dictionary):

```
// SET
NSMutableArray *settings = [NSMutableArray array];
for (UITableViewCell *c in [self.tableView subviews]) {
    if (c.selected) {
        [settings addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
    } else {
        [settings addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]];
    }
}
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:settings forKey:@"settings"];

// GET
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *mySettings = (NSMutableArray *)[defaults objectForKey:@"settings"];
setting1 = [mySettings objectAtIndex:1];
setting2 = [mySettings objectAtIndex:2];
```

On that note, you might consider 2 other options... 1. Just keep all your BOOLs in an array instead of adding them to the cells, then store it when needed; 2. Create a NSObject that is your settings, keep them all in there, and then store the entire object:

```
NSData *myEncodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myApp.settings];
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:myEncodedObject forKey:@"settings"];
```

To do this you have to add encode/decode stuff to that settings object... there's more on storing custom objects around these parts.