# NSUserDefaults fail to save NSMutableDictionary

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

Iam trying to save NSMutableDictionary to NSUserDefaults with this code:

```
NSUserDefaults *def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSMutableDictionary *repositoryData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

[repositoryData setObject:personData forKey:@"persondata"];

[def setObject:repositoryData forKey:@"kUserRepository"];
[def synchronize];
[repositoryData removeAllObjects];
[repositoryData release];
```

But i am getting this msg:

```
    [NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '{
    persondata = "<Person: 0x1ed57e70>";
}' of class '__NSDictionaryM'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

and also the Person Class have NSCoding:

Person.h

```
    @interface Person : NSObject <NSCoding> {
    NSString *name;
    NSString *email;
    NSString *phoneNumber;
    NSString *gender;

    int age;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *phoneNumber;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *gender;
@property (assign) int age;


@end
```

Person.m

```
    @implementation Person
@synthesize name,email,phoneNumber,age,gender;

#pragma mark
#pragma mark NSCoder

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"username"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.email forKey:@"useremail"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.phoneNumber forKey:@"userphonenumber"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.gender forKey:@"usergender"];

    [encoder encodeInt:self.age forKey:@"userage"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if(self = [super init]){

        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"username"];
        self.email = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"useremail"];
        self.phoneNumber = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"userphonenumber"];
        self.gender = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"usergender"];

        self.age = [decoder decodeIntForKey:@"userage"];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Any idea why it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are very specific restrictions as to what type of data can be synced to `NSUserDefaults` within an `NSDictionary`. These include `NSString, NSNumber, NSData, NSArray and NSDictionary`. Use your `NSCoder` methods to serialize to `NSData` (using `NSKeyedArchiver`) before storing in the `NSUserDefaults`.

Also, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: Also, `NSDictionary` can't be saved to user defaults unless they keys are `NSString`s. `NSDictionary` can use other classes as keys, but if you do that then you can't save it to user defaults.