# NSString to NSDictionary as object

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I have `NSString` representation of `NSDictionary`

I created the string like that:

```
 NSString * insertionStr = [dictionary description];
```

Now I want to convert it back to `NSDictionary`

Is it possible ?

Comment: That doesn't "convert" the dictionary - it still is one. All you've done is create an NSString representation of it. Where do you declare the "dictionary" variable? Is that a local variable? A @property?

Comment: Please elaborate why you want to do this. I honestly doubt this is the  way to go about it. From Apple's documentation of the description method *This method is intended to produce readable output for debugging purposes, not for serializing data.* If you wish to serialize the dictionary and store it in a file, see the property list programming guide or archive and unarchive the dictionary.

Comment: You don't have a "string which is a dictionary" at all.  It's not possible as it was never a dictionary in the first place.

Comment: @LevLandau i have tried to store that dictionary in `NSUSerDefaults` but it blamed me with errors :( , so I stored the representation of it as `NSString` and now I want to extract it back as a dictionary

Comment: @mc01 dictionary is a local variable

Comment: @Droppy I have an `NSString` representation of `NSDictionary` 
and `dictionary` is an instance of `NSDictionary` which is actually dictionary`

Comment: So `[NSUserDefaults setObject:dict forKey:@"MyDict"]` didn't work?

Comment: @Droppy no , it claimed that the dictionary is too complicated or something like that , i have googled it , and found that I have to store something like `NSDATA` or `NSString` or something simple :-/
I mean I had runtime error and crash

Comment: @Droppy actually I trying to store an `NSArray` of `NSDictionaries` it didn't allow me , but when I storing an `NSArray` of `strings` like that it does

Comment: If you're going to do this sort of thing, and if the data in the dictionary is "well behaved", you can convert the dictionary to JSON, or (somewhat circuitously) to a "plist".  You would do one or the other if you want to preserve the dictionary across application shutdown/resume.

Comment: (Saving as a "description" is not a good idea -- there is no defined way to "restore" from that format, and it's not even guaranteed to remain unchanged from one iOS version to the next.)

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks , however I find it sad _

Comment: Saving as JSON is virtually the same thing (looks almost identical), except that the data contained within the dictionary must be dictionaries, arrays, strings, or NSNumbers -- no other object types.

Comment: @HotLicks I have done what u suggested and it works , please make an answer , so future users will know what to do thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save a dictionary to a file (or other medium) and be able to restore it later, you should use either JSON or the plist format.

For JSON your data must be limited to a combination of dictionaries, arrays, strings, and NSNumbers.  For a plist it must be one of those or NSDate, or NSData.

For JSON you'd use the methods of NSJSONSerialization to convert to NSData, then save the data to a file.  To restore, load the file into NSData and run back through NSJSONSerialization.

For plist format use the NSDictionary `writeToFile` and `dictionaryWithContentsOfFile` methods.

Do note that by default the objects you get back are immutable.  If you want mutable objects from JSON there is an option on `JSONObjectWithData` called `NSJSONReadingMutableContainers`.  With plists I believe you need to use the more complex plist interfaces (vs using the simple NSDictionary interfaces) that allow you to specify a similar option.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Question and comments i will say ...**NO ...Don't do it like that**.
`NSUserDefaults` has the capability to store object values and its perfectly fine to store NSDictionary

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject: dictionary forKey:@"DetailDict"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

and retrive it use

```
NSDictionary *retrievedDictionary = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"DetailDict"];
```

OR

If you think you think of saving it as a string have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6368867/1704346) and when retrieving the value just convert back the string to Object

Comment: It looks like the OP has objects which cannot be stored in `NSUserDefaults`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282892/nsuserdefaults-fail-to-save-nsmutabledictionary

Comment: and the answer to that question explains well enough what to do.

Answer (score 1):

From the NSUserDefaults documentation for `setObject:forKey`

The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects.

If your dictionary contains contains non-property list objects you can archive and store it to file if all objects in the dictionary implement `NSCoding`.

Comment: Why would he use NSUserDefaults rather than a normal dictionary?

Comment: He was attempting to store his dictionary in NSUserDefaults.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary is represented as key/value pairs. You can create a dictionary with a single value like this:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{@"name": @"Mike"};
```

You can also store multiple key/value pairs:

```
NSDictionary *newDictionary = @{
                                @"firstName": @"Mike",
                                @"lastName": @"Smith"
                               };
```

Later if you want to get the value back out of the dictionary you use the key to get the value back out of it:

```
NSString *first = newDictionary[@"firstName"];
NSString *last = newDictionary[@"lastName"];

// first will now be @"Mike" and last will be @"Smith"
```

Think of a dictionary like an array, but instead of using indexes (numbers) to reference the value you use keys (strings).

Based on a comment made, if you also want to store an array of dictionaries you can do that no problem like this:

```
NSDictionary *firstDictionary = @{@"key": @"value"};
NSDictionary *secondDictionary = @{@"anotherKey": @"anotherValue"};
NSArray *array = @[firstDictionary, secondDictionary];
```

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the question.

Comment: The original question?

Comment: Well that and the progress made with comments, which is still part of the original question.  The user is having issues storing a dictionary in `NSUserDefaults` due to objects which don't conform so he's worked-around it by using a string.  Your answer appears to provide no solution.

Comment: I didn't read every comment to every response, I addressed the original question which mentions nothing about NSUserDefaults...