# Saving NSDictionary with NSMutableArray as a value to NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5

I am storing UIImage in NSMutableArray then storing NSMutableArray into NSDictionary.
Key of NSDictionary is a foldername and value of NSDictionary is a NSMutableArray.
Now how can i store and retrieve NSDictionary in NSUserDefaults.

I have done as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *imageArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[imageArray addObject:selectedImage];


[allFolderWithImageDict setValue:imageArray forKey:@"UniqueFolderName"];

NSUserDefaults *defauktCenter = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defauktCenter setValue:allFolderWithImageDict forKey:@"FolderImageDict"];
[defauktCenter synchronize];
```

But NSDictionary is not saving in NSUserDefaults.

Please suggest with some example

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Store and Retrieve Values of **Custom Objects**, you can use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` Classes :

```
// To Save. . .
NSData *resData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:allFolderWithImageDict];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:resData forKey:@"FolderImageDict"];

// To Load. . .
NSData *respData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"FolderImageDict"];
resultDictionary = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:respData];
NSLog(@"dict :: %@",resultDictionary);
```

GoodLuck !!!

Comment: I got the answer from this link  http://rajuandroid.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-store-custom-objects-in.html

Answer (score 0):

To store `UIImage` objects in `NSUserDefaults` you need to a category implementation for `UIImage` that implements `NSCoding` protocol

here is one:
https://code.google.com/p/iphonebits/source/browse/trunk/src/Categories/UIImage-NSCoding.h
https://code.google.com/p/iphonebits/source/browse/trunk/src/Categories/UIImage-NSCoding.m

from
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.it/2009/03/uiimage-and-nscoding.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using NSDictionary, use NSMutableDictionary.... :)

And to retrieve the data stored in dictionary.....

```
  NSUserDefaults *d = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

  NSString *loadname1 = [d objectForKey:@"FolderImageDict"];

  NSLog(@"%@", loadname1);
```