# Best approach to persist preferences of several User ( NSUserDefaults, XML file or Database)

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am creating one iOS app with the possibility of managing users and login them.

I want to persist the user data settings of every user but I´m not sure what is the best way to do save this setting by each user.

Should I save the data into an xml file, or NSUserDefaults or even saving them into my Parse Cloud Database?

I just want to save a list of user properties when loading a view, but I must have in consideration that my App must load the right parameter for current user.

For example:

User: Peter 
trackingSwitchEnabled: YES

User: Molly 
trackingSwitchEnabled: NO

User: Paul 
trackingSwitchEnabled: YES

Comment: I just can tell that database would be overkill. Dont use it for that purpose.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Don't use the keychain unless you are storing sensitive information.
- Don't use Core Data or XML (unless it's a plist) because it's a lot of work.
- Don't use Parse unless you have a reason to, because your user data would depend on you paying for an account, and the users having connectivity.
- Use NSUserDefaults with key=user, value=JSON string. You can parse that to/from an object.
- Use a compound key if you are extra-lazy, e.g.: key="Mary|tracking", value=YES.

Bonus ASCII art!

```
                           NSUserDefaults   plist    Core Data   SQList
    Full text search           ✘              ✘          ✘         ✔
    Complex search             ✘              ✘          ✔         ✔
    Binary data                ✘              ✘          ✔         ✔
    Allows complex data        ★              ★★        ★★★★     ★★★★
    Performance                ★              ★         ★★★      ★★★★
    Learning curve             ★              ★★        ★★★      ★★★★
```

Comment: Finally, I consider that the best way of solving the problem of multi user settings is by using NSUserDefaults with key=user, value=JSON string. You can parse that to/from an object.

Comment: Instead of a JSON string, can't you also use an NSDictionary? Potentially simpler, because you don't need to parse it. Could also use an NSObject subclass, as long as you implement the [appropriate methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)  More for if you have multiple preferences to save.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use NSUserDefaults, you should use `initWithSuiteName:` to create different database.

[[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName:`USER_IDENTIFY`]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice Guide for Preferences and Settings for an app.

[About Preferences and Settings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i)

In short you should use NSUserDefaults.

Comment: It looks like the best solution, but I´m not sure if I can use NSUserDefaults for many users.

Comment: You can define your own key-value pairs so this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use of NSUserDefault is not a good idea for saving user login details.
It is better to use **Dynamic plist** or xml.
please read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/keychainServConcepts/iPhoneTasks/iPhoneTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000897-CH208-SW1) for another better way.

Comment: It is not about saving login details, but user configuration.

Answer (score 0):

For saving user credentials, I would suggest using [KeychainItemWrapper](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_m.html) class from apple:

You use it to save values like this (e.g. with email/password textFields)

```
        KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"myAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];        
        [keychainItem setObject:txtPassword.text forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];
        [keychainItem setObject:txtEmail.text forKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
        }
```

And then, when you want to get values back from keychain you just:

```
        KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"myAppLogin" accessGroup:nil];
        NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [myDictionary setObject:[keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)] forKey:@"email"];
        [myDictionary setObject:[keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)] forKey:@"password"];
```

Also, don't forget to download KeychainItemWrapper.h and .m from developer.apple.com link I posted on the top :)

So yeah, basically explained what Steve said :)

Comment: Nice information, but in my case is about archiving user configuration profile

Comment: Oh for that, I would use NSUserDefaults, or CoreData :) Depends, how big the data structure is :)

Comment: Oh by the way, I don't think its good idea to use it for multiple users... I would do it just for one user. For multiple, save data into file