# How to set entity in the NSUserDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsuserdefaults

Can we store core date entity into the NSUser NSUserDefault.As i am trying to save the entity .but it returns null at the point where i want to use.it but if i try to save the entity attribute .it returns the the valve.

below is my code sample if i use the following to save the entity

```
    MyEntity *newEntity = [self.fetchController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:newEntity forKey:@"Act"];
```

and use the following to get the entity .the result is null.

```
     MyEntity *entityAtOtherClass =[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"Act"];
```

where as  if i try to store the entity attribute say some string ,then i am able to get the Value for this entity object.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setValue:newEntity.name forKey:@"Activity"];
```

Comment: did you synchronize to nsuserdedefault ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get back the same object, then you don't need to store the whole object - just its object ID.

Storing it is easy:

```
NSString *myObjectToStore = [[[myObject objectID] URIRepresentation] absoluteString];
[[NSDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:myObjectToStore forKey:@"myKey"];
```

Getting the object back is a little harder, as you need to have a reference to the persistent store and context that you want to use; I've assumed they're in `myPersistentStore` and `myContext`:

```
NSURL *myObjectURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[NSDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myKey"]];
NSManagedObjectID *myObjectID = [myPersistentStore managedObjectIDForURIRepresentation:myObjectURL];

NSError *error = nil;
MYManagedObjectClass *myObject = [myContext existingObjectWithID:myObjectId error:&error];
```

Comment: I would not recommend using the objectID like this.  The objectID can and does change.  It is far safer to generate your own unique identifier, store that in Core Data and reference it in the `NSUserDefaults`.  Otherwise on your first migration that value may change.

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra thanks for pointing out .But can you please tell me what exactly you mean "First migration that value may change." and sorry it's been almost a year i have asked the question but i would really appreciate if you can tell me a bit about this. as i still learning the `things` here

Comment: @MarcusS.Zarra i bought the Book "Core Data for the Pragmatic Programmers" Looking forward to explore Core Data more :)

Comment: `-objectID` is intended to be unique for the current application lifecycle.  It is not guaranteed to be consistent however.  That means that it can change *between* lifecycles of the applications.  For example if you do a migration the value will change.  Likewise if you are using iCloud the value can change.

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (emphasize added):

> The `NSUserDefaults` class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): `NSData`, `NSString`,
>   `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`. **If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of `NSData`.**

In other words: if you want to store something that is not a `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray` or `NSDictionary` you need to serialize and deserialize it. If your object supports `NSCoding` you can en/decode using the `NSKeyedArchiver`. You could also serialize a dictionary-with-strings representation, for example.

See also the documentation for [`-[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject%3aforKey%3a).

Answer (score 2):

In order to store a custom object into NSUserDefaults, you need to implement the `encodeWithCoder` and `initWithCoder` methods ([NSCoding protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) in your object.

There is a good answer in this question:
[How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to in your question as "core data entity" appears to be actually an `NSManagedObject` subclass, not an `NSEntity`. `NSManagedObject` instances can't be stored outside of Core Data. Simon's answer is a good approach. Just make sure you have the object's permanent `NSManagedObjectID`, not a temporary one.