# iOS can I implement "Save Game" functionality using NSUserDefaults?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, save, nsuserdefaults

I'm looking at this question about [how to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults), and am interested **if there's something about speed or size limit of NSUserDefaults that would prevent me from storing my single save game file in user defaults?**

For example:

I'm thinking of storing: up to 112 entities, each one can have an "inventory" of up to 17 items, a general inventory of up to 512 items. This will either be serialized/decoded or wrapped in a JSON string.

Let's say the whole data size is 5 Mb - can I store this much in user defaults? Will there be a long delay when storing/writing this much info into user defaults?

Of course I can implement a core data stack, but it seems like a bit of an overkill to do this for a single savegame.

Comment: Store the data in a plist file. Better than NSUserDefaults for this amount of data.

Comment: Think of Core Data more like - do I need all this data loaded at the same time. If not, consider it. If yes, think about saving to a file (JSON or plist) directly.

Comment: Just out of curiocity, is there some way I can save the entire application state and then just restore it, without having to do a savegame?

Answer (score 0):

Apple not recommend to store large data in preferences. One example why is storing preferences in iCloud to synchronize preferences on all devices.

See [following link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud/StoringPreferenceDatainiCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH7-SW1)

In section "Strategies for Using the iCloud Key-Value Store" you can find following:

Each app is limited to 1 MB of total space in the key-value store. (There is also a separate per-key limit of 1 MB and a maximum of 1024 keys are allowed.) Thus, you cannot use the key-value store to share large amounts of data.