# Save id type object in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I want to save id type object value in NSUserDefaults.

```
-(IBAction)sendOrderReady:(id)sender
{
NSUserDefaults *d = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[d setValue:sender forKey:@"sender"];
// [d setObject:sender forKey:@"sender"];
[d synchronize];
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to save button object in NSUserDefault?

Comment: what do u really want to save?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 4):

from the NSUserDefaults class description

`The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.`

so if your id object isn't one of the above instances, then you will have to convert it to one of them, and [this question is what exactly you're looking for.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 0):

With NSUserDefaults you can save objects from the following class types:

NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, NSDictionary

If you want to store any other type of object then you need to archive it or wrap it in an instance of NSData

Answer (score -1):

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"iPhone" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// saving an NSInteger
[prefs setInteger:442 forKey:@"integerKey"];

// saving a Double
[prefs setDouble:5.15 forKey:@"doubleKey"];

// saving a Float
[prefs setFloat:123.45678 forKey:@"floatKey"];

// This is suggested to synch prefs, but it is not needed
[prefs synchronize];
```