# Attempt to set a non-property-list object

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
Prostate *prostate = [Prostate new];
prostate.prostateCheckTimeString = self.prostateCheckTime.text;
prostate.prostateCubeString =self.prostateCube.text;
prostate.prostateAntigemString =self.prostateAntigem.text;
prostate.peeSpeedMaximumString =self.peeSpeedMaximum.text;
prostate.peeRemenderString =self.peeRemender.text;
[mutableArray addObject:prostate];
NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:self.mutableArray];


[Global saveArrayToUserDefault:prostateArray saveValue:tempArray];
NSArray *array = [Global getArrayFromUserDefault:prostateArray];
```

**//Below is my global object**

```
**+(void)saveArrayToUserDefault:(NSString *)userDefaultKey saveValue:(NSArray *)value**
{
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[userDefaults setObject:value forKey:prostateArray];
[userDefaults synchronize];
}

**+(NSArray *)getArrayFromUserDefault:(NSString *)userDefaultKey**
{
NSArray *temp;
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
temp = [userDefaults objectForKey:userDefaultKey];
return temp;
}
```

**-----------------------------------Description ---------------------------------------**

I had Been Search for a while , I know NSUserDefault can only store NSArray , I tried to convert NSMutableArray to NSArray , but still got error

**-----------------------------------Error ---------------------------------------------**

Property list invalid for format: 200 (property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType') Attempt to set a non-property-list object (
    ""

Comment: The problem isn't the mutable array. The problem is you can't store custom objects in `NSUserDefaults`. You have to encode your `Prostate` objects properly.

Comment: Please [do a search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+Attempt+to+set+a+non-property-list+object).

Comment: you can not save any array type of object directly to the User default. Please check this Link . http://stackoverflow.com/a/2315972/2098690 
you can use object mapper for this to set Archivable object https://github.com/roomorama/RMMapper

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement the `<NSCoding>` protocol in your entity class which you wanna save

```
-(void)writeArrayWithCustomObjToUserDefaults:(NSString *)keyName withArray:(NSMutableArray *)myArray {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
    [defaults setObject:data forKey:keyName];
    [defaults synchronize]; }

-(NSArray *)readArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults:(NSString*)keyName {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:keyName];
    NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
    [defaults synchronize];
    return myArray;  }
```

Comment: You've left out most of the important code needed to make this work. As is, this code will crash with exceptions about the `Prostate` class not conforming to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: Thanks Fair enough :)

Answer (score 0):

`Prostate` is your custom object and `NSUserDefaults` does not allow you to save it.
So you have to `Archive` it before saving to NSUserDefaults and Unarchive it when reading back from `NSUserDefaults`.

So your methods to save and read user defaults data should look like:

```
-(void)writeArrayWithCustomObjToUserDefaults:(NSString *)keyName withArray:(NSMutableArray *)myArray {
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myArray];
     [defaults setObject:data forKey:keyName];
     [defaults synchronize]; 
}

-(NSArray *)readArrayWithCustomObjFromUserDefaults:(NSString*)keyName {
     NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
     NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:keyName];
     NSArray *myArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
     return myArray;  
}
```

Comment: You've left out most of the important code needed to make this work. As is, this code will crash with exceptions about the `Prostate` class not conforming to the `NSCoding` protocol.