# App crashes when storing custom object in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have custom class named `User` witch conforms to NSCoding protocol. But when I'm trying to store it in NSUserDefaults I get this error:

```
Property list invalid for format: 200 
(property lists cannot contain objects of type 'CFType')
```

And this warning:

```
NSForwarding: warning: object 0x7f816a681110 of class 'Shikimori.User'
does not implement methodSignatureForSelector: -- trouble ahead
Unrecognized selector -[Shikimori.User _copyDescription]
```

`User` class:

```
class User: NSCoding {

private enum CoderKeys: String {
    case ID = "user.id"
    case Username = "user.username"
    case Email = "user.email"
    case Avatar = "user.avatar"
}

let id: Int
let username: String
let email: String
let avatar: String

init(id: Int, username: String, email: String, avatar: String) {
    self.id = id
    self.username = username
    self.email = email
    self.avatar = avatar
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    id = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(CoderKeys.ID.rawValue)
    username = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(CoderKeys.Username.rawValue) as String
    email = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(CoderKeys.Email.rawValue) as String
    avatar = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(CoderKeys.Avatar.rawValue) as String
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeInteger(id, forKey: CoderKeys.ID.rawValue)
    aCoder.encodeObject(username as NSString, forKey: CoderKeys.Username.rawValue)
    aCoder.encodeObject(email as NSString, forKey: CoderKeys.Email.rawValue)
    aCoder.encodeObject(avatar as NSString, forKey: CoderKeys.Avatar.rawValue)
}
}
```

**Update**
Saving code:

```
let userKeyForDefaults = "apimanager.user"


let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject(user, forKey: self.userKeyForDefaults)
```

Comment: you can't store custom object to NSUserDefaults

Comment: @vivek, even if it conforms to NSCoding?

Comment: i haven't tried, but maybe your class must base on NSObject ? So class User: NSObject, NSCoding

Comment: @Volker, nope, still crashes

Comment: @user3386109, no thanks, I need solution in swift

Comment: can you show the relevant code for adding your object to the user defaults?

Comment: you have to transform your object into NSData before adding it to the user defaults , accordingly to answer herehttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` does not support all objects, just things like `NSString`, `NSDictionary`, and most importantly, `NSData`. This is where the `NSCoding` protocol comes in handy. It allows us to transform custom objects into chunks of  `NSData`. To do this, use the `NSKeyedArchiver` class to turn a custom object that conforms to `NSCoding` to the equivalent `NSData`

```
let obj = User()
let data = NSKeyedArchiver. archivedDataWithRootObject(obj)
/// Now you can store data
```

The docs can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedArchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedArchiver/archivedDataWithRootObject:) and the method you are looking for is

```
class func archivedDataWithRootObject(_ rootObject: AnyObject) -> NSData
```

To get things *out* of `NSUserDefaults`, use the "inverse" class, `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. Its appropriate method is as follows

```
class func unarchiveObjectWithData(_ data: NSData) -> AnyObject?
```

Here is a sample.

```
let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("somekey")
let obj = NSKeyedUnarchiver. unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as User?
```

Note: I may have mixed up some optionals, but you get the jist. The documentation for `NSKeyedUnarchiver` can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSKeyedUnarchiver/unarchiveObjectWithData:).

Edit: Fixing the OP's problem was as simple as correctly using `NSKeyedArchiver` and subclassing `NSObject`.

Comment: Still cannot. But I don't understand why? [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/NUZ4zsl.png)

Comment: @devnikor  Have you tried my solution and subclassed `NSObject`, this is the only thing I can think of .

Comment: @devnikor Check this out, it backs up my thinking. http://www.touch-code-magazine.com/does-not-implement-methodsignatureforselector-trouble-ahead/

Comment: Finally! Subclassing NSObject and NSKeyedArchiver fix it. Thanks