# Casting struct to NSUserDefaults in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, struct, nsuserdefaults

Is there a way I can cast this Swift data set in someway to a form that is acceptable to `NSUserDefauts`?  i.e. `NSObject` `NSSet`? (p.s. I realize `NSUserDefaults` isn't for this type of data, but I'm just testing)

```
struct Users {
        var name: String = ""
        var stores: [Store]
    }

    struct Store {
        var name: String = ""

        var clothingSizes = [String : String]()

    }

    init() {
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if let usersPeople = userDefaults.valueForKey("Users") as?
```

Comment: Pretty sure your are limited in what types you can store in Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2315972/620197 https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:

Comment: But the questions is about casting, right?

Comment: Yes, the examples I've seen  always store arrays or arrays of arrays in NSUserDefaults Core Data etc....my data structure, the Store object particularly, is a string associated with an array of a dictionary, which is what I can't figure out how to store in a non-Swift API like NSUserDefults.

Comment: @PSUSabes but, NSUserDefaults has Swift API. You need to save and then read your data, right? Then you just need to use, `setObject:forKey:` for setting and `objectForKey` for reading. Look at my answer and try it.

Comment: Thanks @flinth but I get NSUSerDefaults does not have a member named setDictionary

Comment: @PSUSabes yes, that's why you can use `setObject:forKey`. I edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use Dictionary. You'll need to make method to wrap data to struct and vice versa.

For example:

```
var users : [String: AnyObject]()
users["name"] = "SomeName"
users["stores"] = yourStoreArray
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(users, forKey: "Users")
```

something like that.

And when you need to get struct

```
if let myDictionaryFromUD = userDefaults.objectForKey("Users") as? [String:AnyObject]{
   self.users = Users(myDictionaryFromUD["name"], stores: myDictionaryFromUD["stores"] as! [Store]) 

}
```

I aslo assume that you will save to userDefaults array of Users. In this case, you will save `[[String: AnyObject]]` but mechanics the same.

Comment: stores isn't just an array though, it has a nested dictionary in it?

Comment: @PSUSabes in my example stores is an array. My example is based on your question and stores is array of Store struct in  your case. It can be Dictionary too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is the best way to do this but you can try this.

```
struct Users {
        var name: String = ""
        var stores: [Store]
    }

    struct Store {
        var name: String = ""

        var clothingSizes = [String : String]()

    }

var Advert = [Users]()

init() {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(Advert[0].name, forKey: "NameYouWant")
}
```