# Save custom class objects in NSUserDefaults in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults, nscoder, nskeyedunarchiver

Im trying to save some objects in an array but my objects are used inherited properties
But when trying to read the object it says

```
  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -decodeObjectForKey: cannot be sent to an abstract object of class NSCoder: Create a concrete instance!'
```

The structure is

```
Service(SuperClass)
      Service1(Subclass)
      Service2
      Service3
```

In this way im using this code

```
var S1:Service1 = Service1()
        S1.apiKey = Apikey.text!
        TableViewController.agregar(S1)
        let datos = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(TableViewController.Servicios!)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(datos, forKey: "ServiciosGuardados")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
```

And this is the classes functions

```
class Servicio:NSObject, NSCoding{
var nombre:String = "null"
var tipo:Int = 0

override init() {}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder = NSCoder.empty()) {
    self.nombre = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("nombre") as! String
    self.tipo = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("tipo") as! Int
}
func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(nombre, forKey: "nombre")
    aCoder.encodeObject(tipo, forKey: "tipo")
}
```

-My problem is in here in Service1 which inherites from Servicio

```
class Service1: Servicio {
var apiKey = "null"


override init() {
    super.init(coder: NSCoder())
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: NSCoder())
    if let apiKey = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("apiKey") as? String {
        self.apiKey = apiKey
    }
}

override func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(self.apiKey, forKey: "apiKey")
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `NSUserDefaults` to save objects that are not of type `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray` or `NSDictionary`.

But you can serialize and save/load your custom objects in a file thanks to `NSCoding`.

Since your class already supports `NSCoding`, use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to store and retrieve your custom objects:

```
// save your custom object in a file
NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(myCustomObject, toFile: "/path/to/filename")

// load your custom object from the file
if let temp = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile("/path/to/filename") {
    self.myCustomObject = temp
}
```

In this example, `myCustomObject` could be a `Service1` instance, or an array of instances, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is :

Storable Types in `NSUserDefaults`

The `NSUserDefaults` class acts very much like something called a Property List (aka plist).  It may be just a fancy interface for a plist, or it may be more, I’m not entirely sure.  Nonetheless, plists are limited in what kind of objects they can store.  The six types plists can store are:

```
NSData
NSString
NSNumber
NSDate
NSArray
NSDictionary
```

Here is obj-c example to store custom objects : [How to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Comment: thanks, but actually my problem is in the inherited class (Service1)