# NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject: Doesn't update object?

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nsdata, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I've followed some other threads and successfully did the save/load custom objects to `NSUserDefaults` using `NSCoding` protocol. But, strange thing is: I can't update the object.

Here's some block of codes (Note: `XUtil objectForKey:` and `setObject:forKey:` is just perform load/save from `NSUserDefaults`)

```
// First, load the object.
+ (id)loadCustomObject 
{
    NSData *encodedObject = [XUtil objectForKey:@"customObject"];
    return encodedObject ? [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedObject] : nil;
}
```

Next, perform update its property, then:

```
// Finally, re-encode and save.
- (void)saveToDefault
{
    NSData *encodedObject = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self];
    [XUtil setObject:encodedObject forKey:@"customObject"];
}
```

So after a few try, I found out that there's something not right with KeyArchiver

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:(NSStringFromSelector(@selector(name))];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];
    self.name = [aDecoder decodeObjectforKey:(NSStringFromSelector(@selector(name))];
    return self;
}
```

First, load object, fine (`name = @"ObjectName"`). Update property (`self.name = @"New Name"`). Call `[self saveToDefault]`.

I put debug after `archivedDataWithRootObject:self` in the second block:

```
po [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodeObject] name]
-> old values
```

So the keyArchiver doesn't update the property, but I'm not sure what to do next.

**EDIT5**

After a day, tried all kind of possible methods, I've become so desperate and converted the whole `NSCoder` object to `NSDictionary` and save without any difficulty. What's the point of using this "Saving custom object to `NSUserDefault`" anyway.... People, please give me a light to this problem.

Comment: Are you calling `[NSUserDefaults synchronize];`?  If your class implements the `NSCoding` protocol correctly, then your code looks like it should work.  The encoding of `"name"` is wrong for a start; the key should be `"name"` all the time.  See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults) question.

Comment: in `XUtil setObject:ForKey` I did call synchronize. And I don't see why the encoding is wrong, the method `NSStringFromSelector(@selector())` return selector name, which is always `@"name"`

Comment: But why such a round-about way of getting `@"name"`?  It doesn't make it more robust or easier to read.  It's unnecessary obfuscation.

Comment: Well, you can say that I really dislike using hard code like that :/ Anyway, that shouldn't be any problem with the encode/ decode process.