# Store custom objects in NSUserDefaults in iOS

Tags: ios

I want to store custom objects in NSUserDefaults.
I read the Apple doc and know NSUserDefaults can store only property lists such as

```
NSArray, NSNumber, NSData, NSDate, NSDictionary and NSString.
```

If I want to store custom object, then I need to implement NSCoding protocol.

I need someone can clarify a little bit for the following class:

```
@interface MyDrawBlock : BlockInfo
{
    CGPoint _blockUpLeft;
    CAShapeLayer* _shapeLayer;
    int _blockColorFlag;
    int _strokeColorFlag;
}
```

I have CAShapeLayer* _shaperLayer in my class. 
How can I store MyDrawBlock in NSUserDefaults?

If I implement NSCoding protocol, then how I can store CAShapeLayer* _shapeLayer.

Comment: You can;t store a file in NSUserDefualts. NSUserDefaults is for storing simple keys/arrays.

Comment: this is not duplicated. My object is different from the given answer. Please read my question carefully.

Comment: This looks like an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Step back and tell us what you are trying to do, and why you think you need to do it that way. In general, if you're trying to encode a view object (And a CAShapeLayer is a view object for the purpose of this discussion) then you're doing something wrong. View objects are for showing content, not for saving state. There is probably a better/more appropriate way to accomplish what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver`.

Here look at this answer for a similar question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315972/4160199

Comment: Thanks for the quick replay, but my class contains CAShapeLayer* _shapeLayer

Comment: No Problem, but I don't see why you wouldn't be able to encode CAShapeLayer. Just encode it as an object.

Comment: Thanks, actually it works for CAShaperLayer

Comment: @JoobLee, note that storing a shape layer in user defaults is a bad idea. (See my comment  to your question)