# Writing an NSCache to disk with NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nscoding, nscache

I need a dictionary to hold a limited number of objects that need to be created with an internet connection and cache them so they remain available when there's no internet connection.

`NSCache` seems ideal since I can specify a limit or it will automatically adjust itself based on available memory, but I can't save the object to `NSUserDefaults`. If I try caching like this, which worked for `NSDictionary`:

```
+ (void)cacheUsers:(NSCache *)users {
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:users];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:kCacheID];
}
```

the app crashes: `[NSCache encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Should I convert the `NSCache` to an `NSDictionary` before caching and then convert again when retrieving? Or is there a better way to save an `NSCache`?

Comment: NSCache doesn't implement NSCoding, so you cannot archive it.

Comment: Also, I wonder how do you plan converting the cache into a dictionary? NSCache has no API for iterating through the contents...

Comment: yea that would be my next question. I guess I have to extend NSMutableDictionary to make it basically the same as an NSCache... ok apple

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: I want to load user objects from the web and cache them so they're always available. But there could be an infinite number of objects, so I need to release memory at some point

Comment: I see. In this case you indeed need to write your own object repository that discards items in a well-defined manner and supports archiving. IMO NSCache wouldn't be suited for this (even if you could archive it), because Apple makes no guarantees regarding its eviction policy. E.g. on iOS all NSCaches are cleared when the app goes to the background.

Comment: ok thanks that answers it

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are trying to save an array with custom class objects,
For that You need to implement the methods named 'encodeWithCoder' in your custom class, in order to save it to NSUserDefault.

To me, You don't need to using the NSCache.

See related answer below:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315972/1982185

Good luck!

Comment: Why not just save an array with custom objects, instead of array with NSCache.

Comment: There could be an infinite number of users loaded, so I need to be able to release some when memory is tight.

Comment: Also, an NSCache is not an array, its a dictionary

Comment: I mean save an array with custom objects to NSUserDefault.

Comment: Oh there was a typo in my code that made it look like an array. Sorry for the confusion. I've updated

Comment: I think you don't want actually to save an NSCache, what you want to save is the object(image or user info) which is cached by NSCache, if this is correct, why not just forget the NSCache,  and save the object to NSUserDefault.

Comment: I see what you mean - NSUserDefault is a also dictionary - but I need an object to manage the memory

Comment: how about follow library:https://github.com/pinterest/PINCache
https://github.com/tumblr/TMCache
https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift