# How to save and retrieve NSObject class using NSUserDafaults in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Hi I want to save and retrieve `NSObject` class using `NSUserDefaults` for that I wrote below code but I am getting exception like below

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSInvalidArgumentException`', reason: 'Attempt to insert non-property list object  for key DATA'

**For saving :-**

```
 SavingBean*savingbean = [[SavingBean alloc]init];
    [savingbean savingData:userName.text :passWord.text];

    NSUserDefaults * defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]init];
    [defaults setObject:savingbean forKey:@"DATA"];
```

**For retrieving:-**

```
defaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc]init];
savingbean = [defaults objectForKey:@"DATA"];

NSLog(@"Username is===>%@",savingbean.userName);
NSLog(@"Password is===>%@",savingbean.passWord);
```

**ModelClas:-**

.h file:-

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface SavingBean : NSObject{

    NSString *userName;
    NSString *passWord;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *userName;
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *passWord;

-(void)savingData :(NSString*)userName :(NSString*)password;

@end
```

.m file:-

```
#import "SavingBean.h"

@implementation SavingBean
@synthesize userName,passWord;

-(void)savingData :(NSString*)username :(NSString*)password{

    userName = username;
    passWord = password;
}

@end
```

Comment: convert it to nsdata first, then you can save it

Comment: You can not save NSObject data in User Default if you want to use in another view controller then pass data in segue or as answered by @jayesh

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set object like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:savingbean];
[currentDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"DATA"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
```

and for get object like this:

```
NSData *data = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"DATA"];
SavingBean *token = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

For Custom class you have to edit this methods in you bean class:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.userName==nil?@"":self.userName forKey: @"userName"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.passWord==nil?@"":self.passWord forKey: @"passWord"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.userName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"userName"];
        self.passWord = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"passWord"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315972/2284065) is most voted similar answer. You can also get good stuff from there.

You can also use [JSON Accelerator](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/json-accelerator/id511324989?mt=12) to create bean class. This is very simple and powerful tool.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SavingBean encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7be83510'

Comment: getting this eception

Comment: You need to make sure your class implements `NSCoding`

Comment: u mean my NSobject class?

Comment: @Jayesh Thanki i post my Custom class so how can i do remaining

Answer (score 1):

From good answer of Jayesh Thanki I tried sample from this question.I followed your coding.First I tried Save and Retrieve directly without encoder and decoder method.

For Save

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:savingbean];
[currentDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"DATA"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
```

For Retrieve

```
NSData *data = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"DATA"];
savingbean = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Now it shows error

> [SavingBean encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc65940fc40
>
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SavingBean encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc65940fc40'

Then I googled most of the answer say

> The NSCoding protocol declares the two methods that a class must implement so that instances of that class can be encoded and decoded. This capability provides the basis for archiving (where objects and other structures are stored on disk) and distribution (where objects are copied to different address spaces).

**encodeWithCoder**

> encodeWithCoder: instructs the object to encode its instance variables to the coder provided; an object can receive this method any number of times.

**initWithCoder**

> initWithCoder: instructs the object to initialize itself from data in the coder provided; as such, it replaces any other initialization method and is sent only once per object.

Then I understood that we must implement the encodeWithCoder and inintWithCoder first in NSObject Class.After that only we should save and retrieve the data.

> ->*encoder is an archiver object*
>   ->*decoder is an  unarchiver object*

Now First we have to implement the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder in SavingBean.m

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{
  //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
  [encoder encodeObject:@"AbhiRam" forKey:@"username"];
  [encoder encodeObject:@"Test@123" forKey:@"password"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder 
{
  if((self = [super init]))
  {
    //decode properties, other class vars
    userName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"username"];
    passWord = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"password"];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Then in ViewController.m

For Save

```
SavingBean *savingbean = [[SavingBean alloc]init];
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:savingbean];
[currentDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"DATA"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
```

For Retrieve

```
NSData *data = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"DATA"];
savingbean = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

Now when I run the application it does not show any error.It works fine now.

Why I give these things here is If anybody sees and tries this answer in some case they can get the error like above.So if they prefer two answer for this question they can very easily understand and get the solution very simply.

[encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder of NSCoding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSCoding/initWithCoder:)