# Convert Custom NSObject to NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdata, nsobject, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to transfer data between 2 devices using bluetooth. I want to convert custom NSObject to NSData.

What is the best way to decode the received NSData into a custom NSObject ?

Thanks!

Comment: You could make your class NSCoding compliant and use the `NSKeyedArchiver`, or a translation into a JSON (and create a `initWithJSON:` custom init), etc.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `NSCoding`. `NSCoding` is a simple protocol, with two methods: `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:`. Classes that conform to `NSCoding` can be serialized and deserialized into data that can be either be archived to disk or distributed across a network.

[NSCoding / NSKeyed​Archiver.](http://nshipster.com/nscoding/)
Here is tutorial of `NSCoding`.

**Archiving**

`NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:YourClass];`

**Unarchiving**

`YourClass *objYourClass = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];`

You can also refer my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324693/2284065). First you have to create Bean Class and implement `initWithCoder:` and `encodeWithCoder:` after that you can Archive `NSData` from bean class object and Unarchive bean class object from `NSData`.

Answer (score 0):

My very simple answer

First we have to implement the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder in NSObject.m and before that I have 2 data(username and password) in NSObject Class.For example I set this.You can understand

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder 
{
  //Encode properties, other class variables, etc
  [encoder encodeObject:@"Dev" forKey:@"username"];
  [encoder encodeObject:@"Test@123" forKey:@"password"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder 
{
  if((self = [super init]))
  {
    //decode properties, other class vars
    userName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"username"];
    passWord = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"password"];
  }
  return self;
}
```

Then in ViewController.m

For Save

```
NSObjectClass *className = [[NSObjectClass alloc]init];
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:className];
[currentDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"DATA"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
```

For Retrieve

```
NSData *data = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"DATA"];
className = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

For More Details Go through My [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38324609/how-to-save-and-retrieve-nsobject-class-using-nsuserdafaults-in-ios/38324693#38324693)