# Storing custom objects as NSDictionary vs NSData

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I was going through some tutorials regarding storing custom objects in NSUserDefaults. I can't figure out which is the better approach and/or benefits regarding storing your model after converting it back to `NSDictionary` and storing the dictionary vs using `NSKeyedArchiver` to store the object in `NSUserDefaults`. As per my understanding you will have to set the `encodeWithCoder`and `initWithCoder` methods which will enable you set the values for various keys and basically convert everything to `NSData`. Converting the model back to `NSDictionary` will also follow the same steps.

So what are the benefits of using one approach over the other or if one approach may cause something to break anywhere?

Using `NSKeyedArchiver` will do something like:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.test forKey:@"string"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.surname forKey:@"surname"];
}
```

And converting model back to `NSDictioanry`:

```
-(NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithModel:(Model *)model{

    NSDictionary *dictionary = @{
                                 @"dict":[model.innerModel dictionaryWithModel:model.innerModel],
                                 @"string":self.test
                                 };

    return dictionary;
}
```

Basically which of the would be better when storing object in `NSUserDefaults`?

**Edit:** So according to the doc linked in the answer, we should use `NSDictionary` to store objects in `NSUserDefaults` (better performance), then why does apple recommend using `NSKeyedArchiver`?

Comment: Have a look at my lib: https://github.com/alexburtnik/SettingsBox It allows you to save custom objects as well as all common Foundation objects and primitives to NSUserDefaults in just few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38324693/2284065) is my answer on another similar question.

You can set object like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:savingbean];
[currentDefaults setObject:data forKey:@"DATA"];
[currentDefaults synchronize];
```

and for get object like this:

```
NSData *data = [currentDefaults objectForKey:@"DATA"];
SavingBean *token = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```

For Custom class you have to edit this methods in you bean class:

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder
{
    [encoder encodeObject:self.userName==nil?@"":self.userName forKey: @"userName"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.passWord==nil?@"":self.passWord forKey: @"passWord"];
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.userName = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"userName"];
        self.passWord = [decoder decodeObjectForKey: @"passWord"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315972/2284065) is most voted similar answer. You can also get good stuff from there.

You can also use [JSON Accelerator](https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/json-accelerator/id511324989?mt=12) to create bean class. This is very simple and powerful tool.

**EDIT:**

> The NSUserDefaults class provides convenience methods for accessing
>   common types such as floats, doubles, integers, Booleans, and URLs. A
>   default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.
>
> Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a
>   mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string
>   as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve
>   using stringForKey: will be immutable.
>
> Note: The user defaults system, which you programmatically access
>   through the NSUserDefaults class, uses property lists to store objects
>   representing user preferences. This limitation would seem to exclude
>   many kinds of objects, such as NSColor and NSFont objects, from the
>   user default system. But if objects conform to the NSCoding protocol
>   they can be archived to NSData objects, which are property
>   list–compatible objects. For information on how to do this, see
>   ““Storing NSColor in User Defaults”“; although this article focuses on
>   NSColor objects, the procedure can be applied to any object that can
>   be archived.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

**EDIT:**

> When defining your app’s preferences, it is better to use simple
>   values and data types whenever possible. The preferences system is
>   built around property-list data types such as strings, numbers, and
>   dates. Although you can use an NSData object to store arbitrary
>   objects in preferences, doing so is not recommended in most cases.
>
> Storing objects persistently means that your app has to decode that
>   object at some point. In the case of preferences, a stored object
>   means decoding the object every time you access the preference. It
>   also means that a newer version of your app has to ensure that it is
>   able to decode objects created and written to disk using an earlier
>   version of your app, which is potentially error prone.
>
> A better approach for preferences is to store simple strings and
>   values and use them to create the objects your app needs. Storing
>   simple values means that your app can always access the value. The
>   only thing that changes from release to release is the interpretation
>   of the simple value and the objects your app creates in response.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/AboutPreferenceDomains/AboutPreferenceDomains.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i-CH2-SW2

Comment: Oops i just added an example! What i wanted to know which is better. Not how to do it!

Comment: i think `NSKeyedArchiver` is more suitable way to store custom object in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: But why is that? Can you please add some example or some reason of how it is more optimized?

Comment: @Rikh, I have edited my answer, if you have to store custom object in `NSUserDefaults` then you have to use `NSKeyedArchiver` otherwise you can directly use `setObject:` method to store `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary` in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: I understand that. What i wish to know is **which** practice is more optimized/preferred and why? Converting custom object to `NSData` using `NSKeyedArchiver` and then storing in `NSUserDefaults`or converting object to `NSDictionary`and then storing it in `NSUserDefaults`

Comment: So basically there is no possible scenario for which `NSKeyedArchiver`would be better for storing values in `NSUserDefaults`?