# User Defaults not saving dictionary contents in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I am trying to add a key and a value to a dictionary then add this dictionary the user defaults and read back into a dictionary object. I have two questions that I would really appreciate any help in,

1) why is the dictionary being read from user defaults empty? Since I added a key and a value to the dictionary shouldn't those be saved to the dictionary I retrieve from user defaults?

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard;
var myDict = [String: String]()
myDict["key"] = "value"

defaults.setValue(myDict, forKey: "myDict")


let mydict2 = defaults.object(forKey: "myDict") as? [String: String] ?? [String:String]()
print(mydict2)
```

2) What can I do to this code if the dictionary stores a custom class that I created as a value or a key so if the dictionary was like this:

```
class Car {
  var engineSize: Int
  var color: String

  init() {
    engineSize = 2000
    color = "blue"
  }

}

class Boat {    
  var surfaceArea: Int
  var weight: Int

  init() {    
    surfaceArea = 3500
    weight = 4000
  }
}

var myDict = [Car: Boat]()
```

how can I save that second dict to user defaults and read it from there?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

This is the answer suggested by ebby94:

```
var myDict = [String:String]()
myDict["key"] = "value";

let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myDict)
UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "myDict")


func foo()

{
  guard let archivedData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "myDict") as? Data
    else
    {
        print("failed1")
        return
    }
  guard var unarchivedDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archivedData) as? [String:String]
    else
    {
        print("failed2")
        return
    }

    print(unarchivedDictionary["key"]!)
}

foo()
```

However this prints failed1, I'm assuming the data wasn't archived correctly. Can this be because I'm running it in playground?

Comment: First just make sure you test it in a real project (playground doesn't work)

Comment: Second you need to make your class NSCoding compliant.

Comment: Third use KeyedArchiever to convert your object to data

Comment: Also just use `set(yourObjectData, forKey: "theKey")` instead of setValue

Comment: Use UserDefault method data(forKey:) to load your data from disk

Comment: @LeoDabus Why post 6 comments? Post an answer or vote to close as a dupe (this must be a dupe).

Comment: The class isnt confront to `NSCoding` yet, you have to implement it to make all the property key-value encode and then archived everything into Data

Comment: @Tj3n I have to do that even for the string class? Can you guide me to any information source that would explain how that is done?

Comment: You will need it doesnt matter the type, because its for the property name, not value, do a quick search it has been answered many times like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315948/how-to-store-custom-objects-in-nsuserdefaults)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to save custom object to userDefault first you need to encode & decode variable then save using archive & get data using unarchive.

```
class Car {
    var engineSize: Int
    var color: String

    init() {
        engineSize = 2000
        color = "blue"
    }
    // Decode
    required convenience public init(coder decoder: NSCoder)
    {
        self.init()

        if let engineSize = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "engineSize") as? Int
        {
            self.engineSize = engineSize
        }
        if let color = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "color") as? String
        {
            self.color = color
        }
    }

    // Encode
    func encodeWithCoder(coder : NSCoder)
    {
        if let engineSize = self.engineSize
        {
            coder.encode(engineSize, forKey: "engineSize")
        }
        if let color = self.color
        {
            coder.encode(color, forKey: "weight")
        }
    }
}

class Boat {
    var surfaceArea: Int
    var weight: Int

    init() {
        surfaceArea = 3500
        weight = 4000
    }

    // Decode
    required convenience public init(coder decoder: NSCoder)
    {
        self.init()

        if let surfaceArea = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "surfaceArea") as? Int
        {
            self.surfaceArea = surfaceArea
        }
        if let weight = decoder.decodeObject(forKey: "weight") as? Int
        {
            self.weight = weight
        }
    }

    // Encode
    func encodeWithCoder(coder : NSCoder)
    {
        if let surfaceArea = self.surfaceArea
        {
            coder.encode(surfaceArea, forKey: "surfaceArea")
        }
        if let weight = self.weight
        {
            coder.encode(weight, forKey: "weight")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, is there anyway you can explain the code a little more. a lot of this is new to me and I would like to understand it decently before I use it. what's required convenience? for self.surfaceArea = surfaceArea would self be the decoder's object?

Answer (score 3):

You can't save a dictionary directly in `UserDefaults`. You'll have to convert the dictionary into data and save it and then retrieve the data and unarchive it into dictionary.

Archive and save to UserDefaults

```
    let myDict = [String:String]()
    let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: myDict)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "myDict")
```

Retrieve and unarchive the data to dictionary

```
    guard let archivedData = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "myDict") as? Data
        else{return}
    guard let unarchivedDictionary = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: archivedData) as? [String:String]
        else{return}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how userdefaults is handled in a playground. Can you try doing this in a new project and update the result?

Answer (score 0):

Userdefaults not work in Playground. you need to implement and start it in an App in Simulator